# A strange behavior about pytorch tensor. Any one can explain it clear?

Tags: python, pytorch

When I create a PyTorch tensor and tried to explore its type, I found this：

```
>>> a = torch.rand(3,5)
>>> a
tensor([[0.3356, 0.0968, 0.2185, 0.9843, 0.7846],
        [0.8523, 0.3300, 0.7181, 0.2692, 0.6523],
        [0.0523, 0.9344, 0.3505, 0.8901, 0.6464]])
>>> type(a)
<class 'torch.Tensor'>
>>> a = a.cuda()
>>> a.is_cuda
True
>>> type(a)
<class 'torch.Tensor'>
>>> a.dtype
torch.float32
>>>
```

Why is `type(a)` still `torch.Tensor` rather than `torch.cuda.Tensor`, even though this tensor is already on GPU?

Answer (score 1):

You got me digging there, but apparaently `type()` as `built-in` method does not work for type detection since `0.4.0` (see [this comment](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/print-tensor-type/3696/12) and [this point in migration guide](https://pytorch.org/blog/pytorch-0_4_0-migration-guide/#the-type-of-a-tensor-has-changed)).

To get proper type, `torch.Tensor` classes have `type()` **member**, which can be simply used:

```
import torch

a = torch.rand(3, 5)
print(a)
print(a.type())
a = a.to("cuda")
print(a.is_cuda)
print(a.type())
```

which yields, as expected:

```
tensor([[0.5060, 0.6998, 0.5054, 0.4822, 0.4408],
        [0.7686, 0.4508, 0.4968, 0.4460, 0.7352],
        [0.1810, 0.6953, 0.7499, 0.7105, 0.1776]])
torch.FloatTensor
True
torch.cuda.FloatTensor
```

However I am unsure about the rationale standing behind the decision and could not find anything relevant other than that.

Comment: Yep! The only difference is that ```a.type()``` got ```torch.FloatTensor```while ```type(a)``` got ```<class 'torch.Tensor'>```; According to this, I guess it's because that the ```type(a)```is a function of python used to output type of variable ```a``` and it is a pytorch tensor but python cannot tell which kind of pytorch tensor it is. On the other hand, ```a.type()``` recalls a method of pytorch, so it can tell the specific pytorch tensor type.

Comment: I guess so, but those are only my speculations, nothing concrete how it really works under the hood (C++ and CUDA namely).